# JBoss AS7 Cluster can't Session Failover

Tags: session, jboss, cluster-computing, failover

My JBoss cluster can't Failover. The cluster with two nodes is managed by domain and the

`httpd-2.2` realize the load balancing.

Steps to reproduce:

1. startup the cluster which include two nodes named node1 and node2
2. login. then find the request is forwarded to node1 .It's meaning that the node1 executes
   the login and keep the session.
3. shutdown the node1
4. continue to execute the web operations

Then the web export the infomation about *session is expired!*

The log of node2 has exception like that:

> [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan] JBAS010322，Failed to load
>   session ; java.lang.RuntimeException:Failed to load session
>   Attributes for session ;

Comment: Is your web app distributable (web.xml)? List the content of your session, and check if each object implements the `Serializable` interface. What are the settings/triggers for session replication? Which JBoss version?

Comment: Thanks for you tips. I sure the web app is distributable. I think if exist some objects not implements the Serializable,when logining, the Jboss Cluster must export the exception of not Serializable. Now the Jboss Cluster running rightly when login,but cannot failover.

Comment: I may be wrong here, but a "NotSerializableException" is not thrown when you add a non-serializable attribute to the `HttpSession`. I have tested this using JBoss 7, there is no exception. And the Javadoc does not mention it either. So, I ask again: Are *all* session attributes serializable? Just add a .jsp, iterate over the names, print the classes and check.